# How long should map projection take?

Tags: matlab

Round 2 to try and ask this question correctly.

I work for a university and have a researcher who is wondering if its supposed to take as long as it does to plot something in map projection.  When she creates a regular figure it takes minutes, but her script takes 2 hours to plot it in map projection.  Her pc is also unresponsive while plotting map projection but fine while creating a regular figure.  The researchers pc is using MATLAB 2020a, has 32g of ram, intel core i-7 7700 3.6 ghz and an old GeForce GT 730 graphics card.  Below are links to the script and data set the researcher is using.  So my question, is it supposed to take this long for map projection or is there something slowing her pc/MATLAB down?  If I am missing any information please let me know.

This link is to the script the researcher is using,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MuifrZIkQdDXOv31Eqzu6uubGAHvfHsZ/view?usp=sharing

This link is to the data set she has been using
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gl0ReRuwIMcxKHzasl6VweWnGx5Hcd7g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you two tried using the built-in profiling facilities? See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html . (I don't have the Mapping Toolbox to test your program myself, and I suspect many people here don't have it, either.)

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate questions. Instead, fix the old one according to [ask], and flag it for being reopened. Note that a question has to be self-contained (don’t depend on external information to be complete and answerable). In your previous question you were asked about certain things like profiling etc. Have you done those? This question is not answerable without going through those paces, and I hope you don’t expect a stranger online to do those for you for free?

Answer (score -1):

With "Map Projection" you seem to address some transformation process of a geographic map?

Have not looked into scripts...
Normally you solve performance problems with local transformations, i.e. you do interpolation on the cells of a grid with exactly evaluated corner points.

EDIT: See, you were not able to describe the context of some function it's pre- and post-condition; may be you deserve your result.